# Is it a bad idea to use a web api instead of a tcp socket for master/slave communication?

Tags: node.js, master-slave

TL:DR; Are there any drawbacks / pitfalls to use a RESTful API instead of a TCP/Socket connection for a master-slave pattern?

---

I'm writing a web application that fetches data from an 3rd party API, calculates statistics (and more), and presents it. The fetched data is stored in a database.

I'm writing this web application with NodeJS and AngularJS.

So there are 2 basic opertions the app will do:

1. Answer HTTP requests from the front end
2. Update the database. This includes: Fetching data, saving data to database, and caching results of some heavy queries every 5 minutes in a in-memory database like redis.

I want to seperate these operations in two applications. The HTTP server shall be the master. The second application is a just a slave, of which as many instances can be spawned.

The master will implement some kind of *task-processor* which just distributes tasks to idle slaves.   The Slave is very *dumb*. It can report about its status (idle/busy and some details like current load etc). You can start tasks on a slave. The master will take care of queueing tasks and so on.

I guess this is common server/agent pattern.

So I've started implenting a TCP Server and Client, but it just feels like so much overhead to do this. A bit like reinventing the wheel. So I thought I just could use a HTTP server on my client which just has two endpoints like

```
[GET] /status 
[POST] /execute/:task
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: A "downside" of a REST-ful [HTTP] API is the overhead. Does it matter? Well, that depends - *does it matter for the task at hand*? Writing the TCP handlers by hand (or the messages sent) *is* to much reinventing the wheel; this is a solved problem with many different implementations/approaches. Of course there are also basic differences to consider such as TCP [generally] being used as a long-streaming connection while HTTP requests are usually short-duration. (And then enter long-polling, WebSockets, etc..)

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR; There are drawbacks to rolling your own REST API for master-slave architecture.

Your server/agent pattern is commonly referred to as [microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html).

Rolling your own REST API might work, but is probably not optimal.  Dealing with [delivery semantics](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/general/message-send-semantics.html) (for example, [at most once vs at least once](http://antirez.com/news/88)), transient failures, polling, etc will likely cause a lot of pain before you get it right.

There are libraries/services to provide varying levels of convenience:

1. [Seneca - http://senecajs.org](http://senecajs.org/)
2. [Pigato - http://prdn.github.io/pigato/](http://prdn.github.io/pigato/)
3. [Kong by Mashape - http://getkong.org](http://getkong.org/)
4. [Webtask by Auth0 (paid) - https://webtask.io](http://webtask.io/)